# Moodle Upgrade via GIT not showing on front end

Tags: git, upgrade, moodle

I ran a GIT upgrade on my moodle site, using their upgrade lines of code. If I go check in terminal, it is showing the code is updated, but on the front end of my Moodle site it still shows 3.5.4 and not 3.6.2. Has anyone experienced this and have any advice for me?
Thanks in advance,
Francesca

Comment: Francesca, sounds like you have a caching problem (client side? server side?)

Comment: Did you get the upgrade screen ? try to go to "notification" in "site administration"..

Comment: I've deleted the cache inside moodle, as well as manually deleting via FTP. I didnt' get the upgrade screen?